# Include a concern module in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, include, require, has-scope

Here is my concern file:  controllerconcerns.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Query_scopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  has_scope :title
end
```

Here is my controller I want to include it in: api_controller.rb

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  require 'concerns/controllerconcerns'
  include Query_scopes
  etc etc etc
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `has_scope' for Query_scopes:Module
```

I have the **has_scope** gem installed and it works fine if I just say `'has_scope: scopename'` within each individual controller I want it applied to... so how can I apply a few lines of 'has_scope' code to all my controllers?

Answer (score 7):

You should follow the naming convention for using concerns, and also include what you want in the `included do` block :)

eg.

```
module QueryScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
     has_scope :title
   end
end
```

and then:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  include QueryScopes
end
```

Comment: thanks!  I think for sake of simplicity, in this case I don't even need include and modules... just the require and the 'included do' block will be fine!

Comment: whoops... nevermind.  It seems I HAVE to use include and define things in modules.  Also, I had to use 'load' instead of require

Comment: actually because rails loads the concerns by default, you don't really need to even require/load anything I don't think :), the above code should just work